# calling dll through php

Tags: php, dll

I need to call a dll that returns a string using PHP.
What would be the best possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a PHP extension that wraps the DLL or create a wrapper (in any language) that can be accessed via shell with [exec](http://php.net/exec).

Comment: is there any other way to lets say initiate a service on the server and get the return using php?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible using native PHP.

I would look into running an operating system level function to do this using `exec()`, like for example `rundll.exe` (for some kinds of DLLs).

If rundll can't do it (it has something to do with managed and unmanaged DLLs, I don't know what that means), the easiest way may be writing a wrapper application that imports the DLL,  performs the necessary actions, and outputs the result.